# Passing property value to a groovy class (not a groovy script) in mule flow

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

How do we pass a property value set in mules global environment into a groovy class (not a groovy script) called in a flow?

Setting the property value in a flow variable before calling the groovy class and then accessing the value in the groovy class as message.getInboundProperty() was one way I was able to do it.

Is there any better way?